# Optimize a query (distance between 2 coordinates)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-administration

I have a big DB of POI its now about 150K but will grow to ~1M

I need to return all points within a certain radius of a point (lat, lon) 
I have this query which worked great until the number of rows increased.
also this query uses about 60% cpu and basically super slow

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (((acos(sin((57.757134*pi()/180)) * 
                    sin((coX*pi()/180))+cos((57.757134*pi()/180)) * 
                    cos((coX*pi()/180)) * cos(((37.616015- coY)* 
                    pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515
                    ) as distance 
FROM 
    places_en
JOIN (   /* these are the query parameters */
      SELECT  
          57.757134  AS latpoint, 37.616015 AS longpoint,
          200 AS radius, 111.045 AS distance_unit) AS p
WHERE 
     description != ''
     AND coX BETWEEN p.latpoint  - (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
                 AND p.latpoint  + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
     AND coY BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
                 AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))
HAVING 
    distance <= 200  
ORDER BY 
    distance;
```

How can I make it better?

Thanks

Comment: You should look into a GIS solution.  Here is a place to start:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-extensions.html.

Answer (score 0):

well if anyone will come across this here is the resault:

i have set up a column "geoPoint" As POINT type.

```
   SELECT
            *,
            (GLength(
            LineStringFromWKB(
              LineString(
                geoPoint, 
                GeomFromText('POINT(".$lat." ".$lon.")')
              )
             )
            ))
            AS distance
            FROM TABLE_NAME
            HAVING distance <= ".$radius."
            ORDER BY distance
```